# Stacking GTK+ widgets

Tags: gtk, widget

Is there a way to put GTK+ widgets in a stack? I.e. put a button over label so that button covers a part of label.

Answer (score 4):

You can use GtkFixed as the layout.  This will allow you to control exact locations of the child widgets, and they can overlap.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to use a Canvas control to explicitly set the positions of the controls - GTK+ works hard to *not* do what you're describing :)

Answer (score 1):

Packing inside a GtkTable appears to allow this, though I didn't test very far - just juggled it in glade a little.

I'm curious what you're looking to use this to achieve.