# Gtk layered layout

Tags: gtk

I am building a simple interface using a 3 row GtkVbox. Inside middle row, I'd like to show a centered image and a small config panel. If config panel is shown, it must appear over the image. How could I simulate a layered panel where the config panel appers in an upper level than the image. Any ideas?

Regards

Comment: Possibly similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604403/stacking-gtk-widgets?

Answer (score 0):

Overlaying widgets on top of each other isn't really what GTK is built for - you might be using the wrong tool for the job. Maybe you should check out [Clutter](http://www.clutter-project.org)?

Comment: The project is developed under GTK so I'd like to find the way to get it work without change the library.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use [GtkOverlay](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkOverlay.html) to put the panel over the image.